# Webpack не работает ни с sass, ни с css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

webpack обрабатывает только js файлы. (Конфиг ниже):

https://pastebin.com/P28HpMhd

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: свежий конфиг...

Comment: А что с ним не так?

Comment: там есть слово css?

Answer (score 1):

Я не нашел style-loader и sass-loader. Ты обрабатываешь только babel.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/issues/439

Тут, теперь, такая проблема, - у меня приложение собирается на сервере.

Comment: у меня тоже на сервере, и все нормально